# JSON API + wordpress URL

Tags: wordpress, api

I'm using a small JSON API for URL shortener that I would like to integrate on all my Wordpress pages.

I know how to render the Wordpress page URL but what I don't know (due to no experience with APIs) is how to render the API result on the Wordpress page.

Here is the API call:

```
http://abc.net/api?api=123&url=LONGURL
```

Here is the API result:

```
{
 "error":"0",
 "short":"http://abc.net/ALIAS",
}
```

Here is the WP url that needs to replace the "LONGURL" above:

```
<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>
```

What I need is to show the "short" result.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've [set](http://www.php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) `allow_url_fopen` to `true` in `php.ini`

```
function get_short_permalink() {
    $permalink = get_permalink();

    $response = file_get_contents('http://abc.net/api?api=123&url=' . $permalink);
    $response = json_decode($response, true);

    if($response['error'] == 0) {
        return $response['short'];
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```

Then replace `<?php echo get_permalink(); ?>` with `<?php echo get_short_permalink(); ?>` in your templates.

What this function does:

- gets the original permalink
- sends a GET request to your API
- transforms the response from a JSON string to a PHP array (see the [docs](https://www.php.net/json_decode) for the `bool $assoc` parameter of `json_decode`)
- returns the shortened link if the `error` code is `0`, or the original link if not

You'll have to work with [cURL](https://www.php.net/curl) if you can't (or don't want to) enable `url_fopen`.

Also, WordPress has a [built-in wrapper over cURL](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_remote_get) that could simplify things a lot: `wp_remote_get`